# Switch case - unexpected behavior

Tags: c, switch-statement, case

I am working on a project en I tried to make the code more efficient but now there's an unexpected problem with my switch case that I can't seem to resolve.

The code is here:

```
switch (start){
            case 0:
            start = 1;
        for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++)
            {
                //le coords du pacman, ghost, T.
                switch (Map[y][x])
                {
                case '@':
                    yPacman = y;
                    xPacman = x;
                case 'G':
                    yGhost1 = y;
                    xGhost1 = x;
                case  'T':
                    yPacman = y;
                    xPacman = x;

                }
            }
        } break;
```

This bit searches an array map once to get the initial coords of 
"@" (pacman)
"G" (ghost)
"T" (pacman in rage mode)

it stores the values of  the coords in global variables.

Now the res of the code:

```
  case 1:
                    switch(Map[yPacman][xPacman])
                    {
                case '@':
                    printf(Map[yPacman][xPacman]);
                    printf("\n\n\nCoordinates Pacman: (%i,%i)\n", yPacman, xPacman);
                    break;

                case 'T':
                    printf(Map[yPacman][xPacman]);
                    printf("\n\n\nCoordinates Pacman: (%i,%i)\n", yPacman, xPacman);
                    break;

                default:
                    printf("test");
                    }

                    switch(Map[yGhost1][xGhost1])
                    {
                 case 'G':
                    break;
                    }

                    break;
            }
```

I made the printf statements to make it more clear and see what happens.

This is the Map Array:

```
 char Map[40][40] = {"#####################",
                    "#  @                #",
                    "# #        #        #",
                    "# #  # ####### #### #",
                    "# #  #           #  #",
                    "# ####  ###   ## #  #",
                    "#      #   #        #",
                    "# #  ## # # # ## #  #",
                    "#    #      #    #  #",
                    "# #  # ## # ## # ## #",
                    "#              #    #",
                    "#####################"
                   };
```

Basically the problem is as follows:

When there's only one "@" in te field (the "#" are walls that it avoids), there is no problem and the pacman moves as I want it to.

When there's both Pacman AND a Ghost in the array map,
using breakpoints and debugging tool, it shows me that it runs the first

```
switch(Map[yPacman][xPacman]){
}
```

statement, but then skips all the possible cases (Pacman, ragemode and even default), and jumps DIRECTLY to the ghost state and makes the ghost do whatever is in the code.

If I delete the ghost and put a normal Pacman and a Ragemode Pacman in the field, only the ragemode will move, and if I only put a normal pacman the pacman does move..

Soomy problem is that it doesn't go through the switch cases properly and I am not sure why..

Comment: Did you just forget the `break` statements between the cases when posting the question, or are they missing in your actual code too?

Comment: Ohhh my God.. I searched hours and hours.. I just forgot the breaks.

You're right. I added the breaks and it works now accordingly..

Okay this is stupid. Thanks so much haha!

Comment: The missing break statements are the cause of the bug I think. yPacman and xPacman will be set to the ghost position, so the second switch won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `break;` in your `switch`, so the code will continue running and assign the ghost the same position as pacman.

Here is an example on how to fix it:

```
        for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++)
        {
            //le coords du pacman, ghost, T.
            switch (Map[y][x])
            {
            case '@':    // Both @ and T denote pacman, so both symbols can share the same code
            case  'T':
                yPacman = y;
                xPacman = x;
                break;  // break added here so that we don't fall through and set the ghost coordinates as well.
            case 'G':
                yGhost1 = y;
                xGhost1 = x;
                break;  // Not really needed, but people tend to forget to add one when adding new cases, so let's put one in for good measure.
            }
```